# Query to append Text to a (distinct) String Array (better solution) to a single semikolon separated String

Tags: google-bigquery

Imagine you have a row with duplicate entries in Big Query in the form of

```
['url-part01','url-part02', 'url-part01', 'url-part01', 'url-part02']
```

What I want to achieve is to

1. Get all distinct values of the array
2. Append a prefix to every value of this array
3. put everything into one string, separated by a semikolon

Result (for a prefix https://www.example.com) should be

```
https://www.example.com/url-part01;https://www.example.com/url-part02
```

I found the following solution:

```
WITH
  example_code AS (
  SELECT
    ['url-part01',
    'url-part02',
    'url-part01',
    'url-part01',
    'url-part02'] AS images_url ),
  sub_image_urls AS (
  SELECT
    CONCAT('https://www.example.com/', strings) AS urls
  FROM (
    SELECT
      ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT string) images_url
    FROM
      example_code,
      UNNEST(images_url) string ),
    UNNEST(images_url) AS strings)
SELECT
  STRING_AGG(urls, ';')
FROM
  sub_image_urls
```

The question is: has somebody a simpler (less nasty) solution for the problem.

Thanks for any advice,

Holm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this one?

```
WITH example_code AS (
  SELECT
    ['url-part01',
    'url-part02',
    'url-part01',
    'url-part01',
    'url-part02'] AS images_url
)
SELECT
  STRING_AGG(DISTINCT CONCAT('https://www.example.com/', strings), ';') AS urls
FROM
  example_code, UNNEST(images_url) strings
```

with a bit of syntax sugar:

```
WITH example_code AS (SELECT ['url-part01', 'url-part02', 'url-part01', 'url-part01', 'url-part02'] AS images_url)
SELECT STRING_AGG(DISTINCT 'https://www.example.com/' || strings, ';') urls
FROM example_code e, e.images_url strings
```